# Shipping costs not updating during checkout

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

We are using the aus post shipping extension.

The price during check out does not reflect this, however Store knows about the price that should be used.

How do i get the shipping price to update?

I have thoroughly read the documentation. I feel this is missing info or a bug!

Please read carefully the below our result:

{exp:store:checkout ...

[image]

Comment: Which version of Store and the Aus Post extension?

Comment: Can you ping us an email? support@exp-resso.com. Make sure you confirm what version of EE and Store you're using along with the version of the Aus Post shipping extension. Cheers.

Comment: I am still facing same issue with store module (2.3.1 version).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: From memory the problem was that we needed to proceed to the next step before shipping was calculated

Comment: Please add this as an update to the original question rather than posting it as an answer. SE isn't a forum, it works best when the question is a single post and contains all the necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was caused by caching issues in an old version of Store (the shipping API response was cached too long, which meant customers sometimes saw a shipping price which didn't reflect changes in the cart). This was fixed in Store 2.2.0.

https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html